# Take closest Points in categories to a specific Location and do calculation

Tags: qgis

I have a points layer with 50+ points in it, and another point layer with only one point in it (a centroid). These points are categorised in 4 groups (labeled 0-3).

I used distance matrix to work out the distance from the points to the centroid, which are now in the points layer table.

I want to:

a) Take the value from the Observation column for the closest point for each of the 4 groups

b) I want to find the difference* in the value between group 0 and 2, and 1 and 4, so I end up with two values at the end.

*In excel this is calculated as ABS(a1-a2) for example.

An example table below:

```
Point   Observation Distance    Group
1   23  4   1
2   14  12  1
3   5   54  1
4   54  2   1
5   7   32  2
6   87  1   2
7   32  78  3
8   45  45  3
9   8   89  4
10  5   3   4
```

---

I've made some progress; I figured out that I can select the nearest point for each group by using Select By Expression:

Distance = minimum("Distance", group_by:="Groups", filter:= "Groups" = 1)

changing 1 for 1,2,3, 4 etc.

But then how to do the rest of the calculation?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using Distance Matrix (Standard NxT method) to create a points layer with a column for distance from a Centroid, and then joining those attributes to the original shapefile. I double checked the distance using the ruler and it matched.